# 'No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments' error occur While Formatting Datetime Field To String ON "dd-MM-yyyy" format

Tags: asp.net, datetime, tostring

I have been working on asp.net 3.5.I want to Convert a DateTime Data from sqldatareader to a String on `"dd-MM-yyyy"` Format. 
But when I use `"dd-MM-yyyy"` formatting parameter as `"rdMonthlyLeave["LEAVE_DATE"].ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")"` browser returns compile error as

> Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to cast it to `DateTime` first:

```
DateTime leave = (DateTime) rdMonthlyLeave["LEAVE_DATE"];
DoSomethingWith(leave.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

or just

```
((DateTime)rdMonthlyLeave["LEAVE_DATE"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

The return type of the DataReader indexer is just `object`, and `object` doesn't have an overload of `ToString` which takes a string. Don't forget that *overloading* is a compile-time decision - the compiler picks the appropriate method with a compatible signature, and only *overriding* occurs based on the execution-time type. In this case there *is* no overload of `ToString` with a compatible signature, so you get a compile-time error.

Comment: I just ran into this issue where I had to cast a property even though it was of type `DateTime` -- but it was nullable (`DateTime? MyDate`)