# Error with ToString has no method that takes one argument in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format a nullable DateTime with ToString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833054/how-can-i-format-a-nullable-datetime-with-tostring)
>   [‘No overload for method 'ToString’ takes ‘1’ arguments' error occur While Formating Datetime Field To String ON “dd-MM-yyyy” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216486/no-overload-for-method-tostring-takes-1-arguments-error-occur-while-format)

I am using the following:

```
@Model.Modified.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy htt")
```

But it gives me a message saying

> No overload method for ToString takes one argument

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `@Model.Modified`?

Comment: DateTime? - I tried the following: ((DateTime)Model.Modified).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy htt")  This worked. Do you think it's because it's DateTime? and not DateTime ??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Modified property on the model may not be of the type DateTime. Try casting it to DateTime before calling ToString on it.

**Update based on the comment**

then all you have to do is

```
  @Model.Modified.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy htt")
```

because the property is nullable

Comment: The property is DateTime?  Would the fact it's nullable be the problem?

Comment: That could be it, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833054/how-can-i-format-a-nullable-datetime-with-tostring